# Generate Java sources from WSDL with Maven and CXF plugin

Tags: maven, cxf, maven-plugin

I have a Maven project. The pom has a goal with the `cxf-codegen-plugin` plugin to generate the web service from a WSDL file.

How could I generate the sources of the web service from this `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute the generate-sources goal:

```
mvn generate-sources
```

The destination of the sources are specified in the pom.xml. By default is target/cxf

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `maven-source-plugin` to generate sources:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will generate source for your main application and tests.

Comment: Thanks! And this plugin does generate allways the sources with the goal mvn clean package?